# How to change weight vectorin LibSVM package?

Tags: java, parameters, svm, libsvm

I am using Java LibSVM package. I tried to change weight vector of svm and according to these new weight vector, I tried to classify test dataset. But the result never changed. I guess I can't change weight vector.

```
trainData = ARFFHandler.loadARFF(new File(starter.getTrainFile()), 8);
testData = ARFFHandler.loadARFF(new File(starter.getTestFile()), 8);

int attributeNumber = trainData.noAttributes();

Classifier svm = (Classifier) new LibSVM();

svm.buildClassifier(trainData);
svm_parameter parameter = ((LibSVM) svm).getParameters();

double[] weights = ((LibSVM) svm).getWeights();
double[] noiseVector = getNoise(attributeNumber, parameter.C);

parameter.weight = weights;
String classification = (String)svm.classify(testData.get(counter));
```